# Using explode function with a variable in the string?

Tags: php

I have an array with $post_id as keys. When save the $data, I saved it as a string:

```
foreach( $data as $post_id => $details )
  $string .= "-pid-$post_id-$details";
```

When use the data, I need to convert it back to array with $post_id as key and $details as value. How to explode it when I don't know what is the $post_id ?

Comment: Just explode on `"-pid-"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do it this way. if you need to serialize a string use json_encode():

```
$string = json_encode($data);
```

Then, when you need to decode it again:

```
$data = json_decode($string);
```

Safe and easy.

Here's the PHP reference: [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Answer (score 3):

php has a method called serialize which will take an array (such as $_POST) and convert it to a string that can then be recreated into an array with unserialize

```
<?php
    // $_POST looks like this for example:
    // $_POST['value'] = 100;
    $string = serialize($_POST);
    echo $string; // Prints '"a":1:{s:5:"value";s:3:"100";}'
    $data = unserialze($string);
    print_r($data); // Prints Array[0] ( 'value' => '100' )
?>
```

I won't lecture about not sanitizing user input, but SANITIZE USER INPUT.

[serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

[unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

*Note that this is a binary string which may include null bytes, and needs to be stored and handled as such. For example, serialize() output should generally be stored in a BLOB field in a database, rather than a CHAR or TEXT field.*  -- from php docs

Comment: `serialize()` produces a binary string that may contain null bytes, amongst other things. It won't necessarily be safe in places where a JSON string will.

Comment: @MikeW added to note to answer.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to explode the string using

explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )

This will return your data as an array

for example

```
foreach($data AS $post_id => $details) {
  $string .= "|||$post_id||$details"
}
```

then to get your data back out of string

```
    $newArray = explode('|||', $string);

foreach($newArray AS $key=>$val){
   $holding = explode('||', $val);
   $finalArray[$holding[0]] = $val;
}
```

Now you will have an array with key being the id and val being the details for each of the items in the string.

EDIT:

Or use serialize and unserialize like Brombomb suggested.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question...

```
$temp = explode('-pid-', $string);
array_shift($temp);

foreach ($temp as $item) {
    list($post_id, $value) = explode('-', $item);
    $data[$post_id] = $value;
}
```

[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and associated [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) may be a better option for "stringifying" your data in the first place. However, there may be a legitimate reason for doing it the way you've chosen to do it.

Comment: what if there's a `-` in the `post_id`?

Comment: Then you're screwed because there are no other delimiters to go off of.